# How do I perform validation on a product import file before doing the import and get back any errors?

Tags: import, magento-1, importexport, validation

I would like to locate a tool that validates a product data import file before we actual perform the import.

I would like the tool to validate the file and let me know if the file is ok or if there are issues that need to be resolved. If there are issues, it would be nice to know what those issues are.

Does anything like this exist already?

Comment: Did you tried the default Magento import?

Comment: Yup ... the import is not really designed well for validating a file is in the proper format.

Comment: What makes you say that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento *does* validate the CSV before importing it, it just does a terrible job at explaining what exactly is wrong when validation fails.

The open source extension [AvS_FastSimpleImport](https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport) adds a few (backwards compatible) improvements to the default import, amongst others more meaningful error messages. See if that helps you.